# Is this a known forest search algorithm? If it is, what is its name?

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, tree-search

The problem is: Given this kind of forest:

[image]
if we have a node, how can we get the descendants of it?

I thought this algorithm that I think is pretty efficient when talking about reading all descendants adding some little overhead in the writing(it's not too much):

Firstly, to simplify, let's suppose that the number of root nodes is limited to N. We then will need to store a list with the N first primes. When we create the first node we will assign the 2nd prime of our list (3) to a field name treeId, the second root node gets the 3rd prime, and so on (we can keep a  counter of how many roots there are).

To create a child of a parent, we will take the parent's treeId and recursively multiply to the parent of parent treeId and then multiply by 2 (the first prime).  To know all descendent of a node with nodeId = k, we can do a linear search and get all nodes whose treeId is different than k and is divisible by k.

We can remove the limit of N records as root creating another index treeGroupId so that a child will inherit the same treeGroupId of the parent and we verify if two nodes have the same treeGroupId to then apply the first verification algorithm.

My question is: Is this a known technique to search for Tree decendents? Is there any flow in this algorithm. If there's can we have better result?

Comment: *"Given a node from a tree [...] let's suppose that the number of root nodes is limited to N."*: if it is a tree, then what do you mean with *multiple* roots? A rooted tree only has **one** root. Secondly, I don't understand the problem. In which data structure is the tree defined? For example, if it is an adjacency list, you can find all descendants by traversing that data structure.

Comment: My tree knowledge is not great, but I think that I meant a multi-tree or a tree that can have multiples root. I don't know if multitree it's the right definition, if it's please someone confirms me for me to edit the post.

Comment: Maybe you mean a *forest*, i.e. a collection of trees. Could you edit your question and describe how this graph is represented in a data structure?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't draw it right, a node shouldn't be able to have two parents. I will correct that.

Comment: OK; that is a forest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of prime factorization, one known solution strategy is to use a so-called factor tree.